# Swift 2 - Method not being called through delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, swift2, xcode7

Hello learning swift and am stuck with calling a method through delegate. Checked multiple answers with similar issues and have tried the solutions but have not been able to successfully apply them to my own situation however I am close.

I have a delegator class named ViewController that holds a variable I would like to change. I have another view called MoodScroll which serves as the delegate. Moodscroll has a button being used to change the value for the variable in ViewController.

**ViewController :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, MoodScrollDelegate { 

    var alarmSoundType: String?

    func acceptData(data: String?) {        
        alarmSoundType = "\(data)"
        print(data)
    }
}
```

**MoodScroll :**

```
protocol MoodScrollDelegate {
    func acceptData(data: String?)
}

import UIKit

class MoodScroll: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func WTF(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.delegate?.acceptData("hello")
        print("function called")
    }
}
```

The IBAction calls fine as it prints "function called" in the console however it doesn't pass the value to ViewController as alarmSoundType remains nil and also the print command is not called in ViewController as well.

Comment: Where you declare MoodScoll object under ViewController class ?

Comment: check if self.delegate is nil before you call it, otherwise you haven't assigned the delegate properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you still have some confusion about delegation : if `ViewController` conforms to `MoodScrollDelegate` protocol, then your `ViewController` object will be the delegate, not the `MoodScroll` object.

Where do you set the `delegate` property of your `MoodScroll` object ?

- If this object is created programmatically from your `ViewController` object, you should set it after initialization :

  ```
  myMoodScrollObject.delegate = self
  ```
- Is the object is created using Interface Builder, you can either use an outlet variable for `delegate`, or set it in `prepareForSegue:sender` of your `ViewController` class :

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if let scroll = segue.destinationViewController as? MoodScroll{
          scroll.delegate = self
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One picky note: the way you have described your problem, it's actually `ViewController` what you should call the delegate of `MoodScroll`. Most likely you're probably forgetting to set the delegate property of `MoodScroll`.

I don't know how these two view controllers relate to each other in your code, but very often you would set the delegate property in the `prepareForSegue` method of `ViewController`, for example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueToMoodScroll" {
        let moodScrollController = segue.destinationViewController as! MoodScroll
        moodScrollController.delegate = self
    }
}
```